# Scrapy - Optional hxs.select

Tags: select, xpath, scrapy

So, my issue is that, when I'm extracting data, there are a couple of entries on the page that, because there isn't a link also associated with them, they don't get selected:

To better explain here is the `hxs.select` statement that gets almost all of the data:

```
 opening = hxs.select('//div[@id="body"]/div/table/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td/table[2]/tr/td[7]/font/a/text()').extract()
```

This statement gets all but 3 opening movie dates.  The three missing dates, as I mentioned, don't have a link associated with them and are actually found at:

```
 hxs.select('//div[@id="body"]/div/table/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td/table[2]/tr/td[7]/font/text()').extract()
```

*Notice: there is no `/a` found at the end.

I would just add an additional statement to get these, but I need all of the information in order.  I also have statements that get a movie title and grossing amount.  I then take these statements and iterate through them to pair them up with where they belong- I can't do this if I add another statement to separately deal with them.  Any suggestions?

::::Data:::::
Here is the url of the data I'm trying to get [BoxOfficeMojo](http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/alphabetical.htm?letter=A&p=.html)

A quick note: If you use Firebug to view the xpath, it adds `tbody` which doens't actually exist (it adds it in).

Here is what a normal opening date looks like:

```
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="right">
   <font size="2">
      <a href="/schedule/?view=bydate&release=theatrical&date=2010-06-11&p=.htm">6/11/2010</a>
   </font>
</td>
```

Here is what one of the 'problem' opening dates look like:

```
<td bgcolor="#f4f4ff" align="right">
  <font size="2">11/20/1981</font>
</td>
```

Comment: Please post example data.

Comment: As @JensErat said, example data would be more than helpful. I am also wondering if the different elements for one movie (title, grossing amount, opening data) might have a common ancestor so you would not need *to pair them up with where they belong*: you would have, e.g., `movies = hxs.select('//div[@id="body"]/div/table/tr')` and then `for movie in movies: opening_date = movie.select('td/table/tr[2]/td/table[2]/tr/td[7]/font/text()')` ...

Comment: @JensErat I added sample data and a link!  Thank you for looking!

Comment: @pault. I added sample data and a link! Thank you for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select all text nodes within that `<font/>` element using the descendant-or-self-axis step `//`.

```
//div[@id="body"]/div/table/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td/table[2]/tr/td[7]/font//text()
```

Comment: Works!  Thank you so much for taking the time to address my issue! Marking 'answer accepted' and upvote!